Breakthroughs of 2024
Now that Quanta Magazine's 2024's Biggest Breakthroughs in Math video is out, we can probably expect that someone, sooner or later, will post a similar question on MathOverflow. Last year, there was a a lot of discussion about the appropriateness of such questions. While there were some vehement objections, a clear majority of the community favored this type of question.
Should perhaps a moderator post the question this year, to avoid re-hashing the debate all over again?

But I want the rep!!1!!1!one!

Bogdan Grechuk posted it: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/484742

@SamHopkins And predictably, it has led to a close/reopen war. So much for trying to head off this mess. :-(

I think the MO users should use the opportunity to complain that their own great work was not featured in Quanta. I’ll start. Everyone look at my papers.  ;-)

@Timothy Chow. Ok, and what's now? The question is now opened 7 days, everyone who wanted to say something had this opportunity. The answer stating "If there is to be a post like this at all, I'm in favor of a moderator posting it. So the moderator can self-cw the question too." received 16 upvotes againt 1 downvotes. And... nothing else happening, except of deleting my question. No active discussion, no action. When do you plan to summarize the discussion and post the question as a moderator?

@BogdanGrechuk: Did you even read Federico Poloni‘s comment on your answer?  Those 7 days occurred during a major holiday week, and I suspect many people are not paying that much attention to MO right now.  Plus, the actual official moderators (which do not include Timothy — I think you might need to go read up on how this site works) are currently short-staffed.  You need to chill and stop demanding immediate action on something that is not at all urgent.

For several years, there was a nice tradition to discuss interesting mathematical results of the year exactly during this holiday week. I think the place was ideal (do you know a better place to ask and answer this question than MathOverflow?). The timing was also ideal - many people are overloaded by teaching and admin duties at normal times, and holiday is an ideal time to read about great new results in various areas of mathematics (and those not paying that much attention to MO during holiday could enjoy the question later). It is unfortunate that this tradition is being killed.

@BogdanGrechuk I don't know why you're concluding that "this tradition is being killed." The jury is still out, as far as I can tell. If you'll permit an analogy, your actions seem akin to those of a vigilante who rushes to hang the defendant while the jury is still thinking, and then when prevented from doing so, complains that the defendant is being acquitted. (And that Timothy Chow, who is a bystander not on the jury, is taking too long to act.)

I meant the tradition to have this question at the ideal place (Mathoverflow) at the ideal time (during the holiday, see my comment for explanation why I think this time is ideal). The tradition to have this question AT ALL may still survive.

@BogdanGrechuk I still don't know why you' think that that tradition is being killed. The jury could come back and rule in favor of your proposal for all future years.

@BogdanGrechuk: As Timothy says, it is not clear that this "tradition" is being killed.  I also think you're getting overly fixated on something that is far less important and central than you're making it out to be.  A far more important tradition here is community moderation by consensus.  Insisting on having things your way and immediately is not very collegial.

I feel that the "consensus tradition" should work other way around, with "freedom to ask" by default. That is, "questions of any given type A are allowed until the consensus is reached to delete all type A questions", rather than "questions are deleted on the basis that the consensus is not yet reached to allow such questions".

@BogdanGrechuk I agree that that's a sensible principle in general. The current question is an exception because it has a track record of vehement disagreements. I don't ask a meta question about every topic I want to post about. I asked about this one specifically because of its known controversial nature, and wanted to have a discussion about whether a moderator should post it. We seemed to be moving toward consensus (even you said you were in favor of a moderator posting it) and were waiting for an actual moderator to respond, until you jumped the gun and hijacked the process.

I agree that my holidays this year felt less festive as a result all this nonsense; I also enjoyed reading these questions during the holiday break in past years. MO is beginning to feel like it has all the useless political dynamics present in academic faculties. But maybe it’ll improve in future years, as suggested above.

Converted from a comment:

If there is to be a post like this at all, I'm in favor of a moderator posting it.

And another one:

So the moderator can self-cw the question too.


"We can probably expect that someone, sooner or later, will post a similar question on MathOverflow"
You are completely right! This is me who posted this question last year Breakthroughs in mathematics in 2023 , I would really like to see it again, and, given $\approx 100$ upvotes, many others like this question as well. So, I will post it if noone else do.
However, I completely agree that it would be better if a moderator post it this year.
So, should I wait for a moderator or post myself?

I’d say give em’ 24 hours from the time you posted this — if they don’t get around to it, merry christmas! (and merry christmas anyways if they do ;^)

Given that there is a question on meta, posting such a question without some kind of consensus here would in my opinion violate the spirit of the rules.  Given the response Alec Rhea has gotten to his many meta interventions on this and other topics, I do not think his opinions reflect the mainstream consensus here.  I expect that right now a question like this would be quickly downvoted and closed.

This question is posted 19 of December, 5 days ago. You (moderators) have enough time to reach a consensus and post the question yourself. Instead, nothing is happening, even no active discussion. I will wait a little bit more, and then ask.

Last year it was indeed downvoted a closed (twice!), but then upvoted and reopened. The final score is 12 downvotes and 105(!) upvotes. A vast majority of Mathoverflow users really enjoy the question and learn a lot of new exciting developments. I really encourage you to not play this "close and reopen" game this time. If you do not like the question, just ignore it, and let other people enjoy it!

In fact, it should be other way around! Instead of "posting such a question without some kind of consensus here would violate the spirit of the rules", I think that voting to close the question without some kind of consensus here (I mean consensus to close it) would violate the spirit of the rules!

@BogdanGrechuk The moderator team is short-staffed right now, since two people just left. Five days in the holiday season, including a weekend, is not much. (For instance, I have a flag for moderator attention that has been pending for over a month.) I think it was inappropriate to act this quickly, going against the consensus decision on Meta, which was to have a moderator do it. What's the reason for this hurry? It's a question on achievements in 2024, and 2024 isn't even over yet.

"A vast majority of Mathoverflow users really enjoy the question and learn a lot of new exciting developments." That's not evidenced by the numbers. A vast majority of MathOverflow users are indifferent (well, a vast majority are spectator only). This applies equally well to questions that I do like, but I do feel that "OMG so many upvotes" is not a great metric

For what it's worth, I am still against such questions, but I am in the minority, so will go back to deleting some of the rubbish and bad-faith answers that Alec Rhea seems to think disappear of their own volition.

(I just wanted to say to @BogdanGrechuk that despite my comments, and my known negative views, I have not downvoted this answer, since I do think that in the current setup meta.MO remains one of the few places where different opinions can be set out for people to see.)

@YemonChoi I appreciate you Yemon, and you're not wrong; apologies if anything I've typed on here has given any impression otherwise.

The downvotes on this answer seem a bit strange to me. The content of the answer doesn't seem objectionable. Perhaps some people want to punish Bogdan Grechuk for his impatience in posting the question before there was any chance for any moderators to react, and are using downvotes as a proxy for that? That doesn't seem to be an appropriate use of the voting system.

A plausible interpretation is that downvoters wish to signal that "no, the answerer should not be the one posting it, but rather a moderator should do it". Downvotes are often used to express general disagreement in meta, where they do not produce a reputation penalty.

May be post under different name - Noteworthy achievements in and around 2024? Like it was in 2010
